# Mostrar ultimo registro en un Group By de MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT B.id,B.linea,B.DateTime,B.EndDate,C.id_employee,A.id_empatarollos, A.psb_hr, E.description, SUM(psb_produc) AS TotalProduction , 
SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalRateExpect,
SUM(scrap) AS TotalScrap
FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
    ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees C 
    ON A.id_employee = C.id_employee
INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_employees D 
    ON A.id_empatarollos = D.id_employee
INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_hours E
    ON A.psb_hr = E.id_desc
WHERE A.DateTime>= '2019-10-16 06:40:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2019-10-16 16:10:00' AND A.hour_psb = '1S_HOURS'
GROUP by B.linea
order by B.DateTime DESC
```

Con esa consulta obtengo la siguiente informacion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el campo descripcion deberia obtener mi ultimo registro que es 
02:00 - 03:00

Comment: De las dos manera de hecho ignora completamente esa condicion si lo quito me sigue ordenando de la misma manera lo que me trae agrupado.

Answer (score 1):

Por que en la condición estas diciendo que el tiempo sea mayor a 06:40 y tu estas buscando uno menor a este.

al quitar la condición te arrojara el mismo el resultado por la misma razón.

```
WHERE A.DateTime>= '2019-10-16 02:00:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2019-10-16 16:10:00' AND A.hour_psb = '1S_HOURS'
```

seria algo asi